# Deployment error Node.js 8 ... Functions deploy had errors with the following functions: dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Attempting to learn and run a very basic actions for the Google Assistant (Level 2) in codelabs by Google. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#2

Running OSX 10.14.5 on a MB Pro 2018. Working in Terminal and using Atom for file editing.

I completed level one and am getting all sorts of permissions errors and function fulfillment errors with npm and firebase.

I was not able to simply install npm through the command npm install. Had to give myself permission to install to the correct folder. Then I had to add dependencies myself as well as point to the correct engine in my package.json

Finally I was at a place where I can command install npm and it completes with no errors. Next I attempt 
    firebase deploy --project PROJECT_ID

I get the following error

```
=== Deploying to 'actions-codelab-a9731'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (55.46 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment(us-central1)...
⚠  functions[dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/apps.js:25:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment


To try redeploying those functions, run:
firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
Richards-MacBook-Pro-2:functions richardr$
```

My pkg.json file is as follows

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "ajv": "^5.5.2",
    "eslint": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3"
}
}
```

And this is my index.js

```
// Copyright 2018, Google, Inc.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the 'License');
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an 'AS IS' BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
app.intent('favorite color', (conv, {color}) => {
    const luckyNumber = color.length;
// Respond with the user's lucky number and end the conversation.
    conv.close('Your lucky number is ' + luckyNumber);
});

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try yo use `npm install --save firebase-admin` or to move firebase-admin to dependencies and not devDependencies. Be sure to use Node.js 8.13.0 or higher. [firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin)

Comment: Tried this $ npm install --save firebase-admin
+ firebase-admin@8.1.0
updated 2 packages and audited 3267 packages in 7.709s
found 0 vulnerabilities 
 
Got same error after deploying the project.

Comment: Are u sure that your firebase-admin is on your dependencies and not on your devDependencies?

Comment: I am not. Is that under fulfillment in Dialogflow? How can I check this?

Answer (score 3):

Change your package.json to this:

Edit: It seems there is missing `firebase` on the `devDependencies`

From `firebase-tools`[package.json](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/package.json)

```
"dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^5.5.2",
    "eslint": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3",
    "firebase": "^2.4.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.1"
}
```

After that run:

```sh
npm prune
npm install
npm update
```

**Edit:**

You can try this to install all firebase at once:

```sh
# By default npm is set to --save but seems missing -dev on the documentation 
# with only --save this will go in dependencies and not devDependencies
npm install firebase firebase-admin firebase-functions --save-dev
```

see [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html) for more options.

Comment: Changed my package.json to the above and then ran npm prune and got the following errors.npm ERR! file /Users/richardr/codelabs-nodejs/level2/functions/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token : in JSON at position 14 while parsing near '"dependencies": {
npm ERR! JSON.parse     "actions-on-...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the response here [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/package.json)