# not able to deploy firebase function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

Hi I am unable to deploy functions using firebase, I am getting the below error.
On trying to look at the logs could not find anything concrete.

If someone can please help me to resolve this issue.

Below are the necessary details.

error displayed :

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        app(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

On running function:log got the below :

```
2022-09-15T08:09:56.119842Z ? app:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-09-15T08:09:56.119851Z ? app:     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/index.js:10:32)
2022-09-15T08:09:56.119860Z ? app:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
2022-09-15T08:09:56.119869Z ? app:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-09-15T08:09:56.119877Z ? app:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-09-15T08:09:56.119893Z ? app:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-09-15T08:09:56.119902Z ? app:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-09-15T08:09:56.120112Z ? app: Could not load the function, shutting down.
2022-09-15T08:09:56.385832481Z E app: Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging

2022-09-15T08:09:56.573338Z E app: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"akhilmodi1988@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app"}
2022-09-15T08:12:27.847972Z N app: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"akhilmodi1988@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"122.179.194.233","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2022-09-15T08:12:27.950588Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.DeleteFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.delete","granted":true,"authorizationLoggingOptions":{"permissionType":"ADMIN_WRITE"},"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app","request":{"name":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.DeleteFunctionRequest"},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}
2022-09-15T08:12:30.436268Z N app: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"akhilmodi1988@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.DeleteFunction","resourceName":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app"}
2022-09-15T08:13:04.366285Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"akhilmodi1988@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"122.179.194.233","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/11.8.0,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2022-09-15T08:13:04.714274Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.sourceCodeSet","granted":true,"authorizationLoggingOptions":{"permissionType":"ADMIN_WRITE"},"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1","request":{"parent":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlRequest"},"response":{"uploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-975633983912.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/20dd78fd-5c6a-4b23-8d2a-abce039a468e.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-284892888168@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1663231384&Signature=o24h25y7yLfKyAzOs8jE8%2BRiXQs9KzeIU2unV6TMBFLYSccAmvzKGB3qk0ps2nXZL0EpBQSAXqhj9nFxTLOWA8AxmS4bD0Z1vBuMpbBNps8mI%2FeY1k5wPnpDdPupG7CLIm%2FHd6H8iXhuF7CTJ7V8C6x%2FIOQP1XiEdOduwoGbUF%2BL9JAn4OpR4JCThIOkCHUu1zkb2lO6otqsfj%2BIYWNQTIJom5c4NgvlzDLFq2sRm2IFSmXhMUa1DVJy7zUEIJVCEdJn1n9MoAQdKqNSC%2BZ5XQSl0uylK5wQI1SyCi%2F32SDEzUK4QZV45dy8XTI2rIOIwdjo7w9s%2BadPzeeDVcN%2FqA%3D%3D","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlResponse"},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}
2022-09-15T08:13:04.706769Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"akhilmodi1988@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","resourceName":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1"}
2022-09-15T08:13:06.711244Z N app: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"akhilmodi1988@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"122.179.194.233","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/11.8.0,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2022-09-15T08:13:07.105263Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.create","granted":true,"authorizationLoggingOptions":{"permissionType":"ADMIN_WRITE"},"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app","request":{"location":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1","function":{"entryPoint":"app","name":"projects/pixstory-biz/locations/us-central1/functions/app","httpsTrigger":{"securityLevel":"SECURE_ALWAYS"},"dockerRegistry":"ARTIFACT_REGISTRY","runtime":"nodejs16","labels":{"deployment-tool":"cli-firebase"},"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-975633983912.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/20dd78fd-5c6a-4b23-8d2a-abce039a468e.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-284892888168@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1663231384&Signature=o24h25y7yLfKyAzOs8jE8%2BRiXQs9KzeIU2unV6TMBFLYSccAmvzKGB3qk0ps2nXZL0EpBQSAXqhj9nFxTLOWA8AxmS4bD0Z1vBuMpbBNps8mI%2FeY1k5wPnpDdPupG7CLIm%2FHd6H8iXhuF7CTJ7V8C6x%2FIOQP1XiEdOduwoGbUF%2BL9JAn4OpR4JCThIOkCHUu1zkb2lO6otqsfj%2BIYWNQTIJom5c4NgvlzDLFq2sRm2IFSmXhMUa1DVJy7zUEIJVCEdJn1n9MoAQdKqNSC%2BZ5XQSl0uylK5wQI1SyCi%2F32SDEzUK4QZV45dy8XTI2rIOIwdjo7w9s%2BadPzeeDVcN%2FqA%3D%3D"},"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.CreateFunctionRequest"},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// const admin = require('firebase-admin');
//  admin.initializeApp();
const express = require('express');
//require('./db/mongoose');
require('../db/mongoose');
//const notification = require('./db/models/notification');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const userprofileInformation = require('../routers/userprofileinfo');
const userCampaigninformation = require('../routers/userProjectInformation');
const searchPerson = require('../routers/search');
const filter = require('../routers/filter');
const multer = require('multer');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
let fs = require('fs');
const loginDetails = require('../routers/login_page');
//const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const UserController = require('../routers/user_controller');
require('dotenv').config();
const filterPage = require('../routers/filter');
var cors = require("cors");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');
const controller = require('../controllers/razorpay_controller');
const excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json');
const userProfile = require('../models/search');
const issueRaiseUser = require('../routers/user_issue');

app.use(cors()); 

const portCheck = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.use(express.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../pix/public-flutter')));
app.get('/', (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../pix/public-flutter/index.html'));
});


app.use(UserController);


app.use(userprofileInformation);


app.use(userCampaigninformation);

app.use(filter);

app.use(issueRaiseUser);

//app.use(searchPerson);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "convert-excel-to-json": "^1.7.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
    "JSONStream": "^1.3.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.1",
    "mongoose-sequence": "^5.3.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "n": "^9.0.0",
    "natural": "^5.2.3",
    "node-nlp": "^4.24.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "otp-generator": "^4.0.0",
    "razorpay": "^2.8.1",
    "remove-stopwords": "^1.0.3",
    "stable": "^0.1.8",
    "stopword": "^2.0.2",
    "stripe": "^9.11.0",
    "twilio": "^3.78.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

File structure:

```
[![Files][2]][2]



  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BGj7.png
```

Comment: Seems firebase dependencies are missing  in your package.json. Check this stackoverflow  [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662535/18265638) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259845/18265638)

Comment: Hi still facing the same issue...tried link1 but error while loading the package whereas no impact from the second link provided.

Comment: Additionally on checking the package.json I can see that "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.18.0", are already loaded

Comment: Have you gone through this troubleshooting [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#global) & please check this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855195/18265638) once

Comment: Hi can you tell me if the router and models folder needs to be shifted within the function folder for deployment?

Comment: Basically all source code must be inside the "functions" folder for deployment. The CLI will only deploy content from that folder

Comment: Hi I just transferred all the files and folders in the function directory but still facing the issue

Comment: Looking at the Error it points to the require on line 6 (column 1) as the source of the failure,  please verify the line numbers of the source code as you didn’t provide line numbers,so  counting the line numbers,line 6 is the following `require('../db/mongoose');`.So the error seems to be that the required package is not available in the location.  Please check the installation of the package and ensure it is correctly located.

Comment: Hi the mongoose issue was resolved after shifting all the files within the function folder but now getting error when trying to call router files..I have updated the logs and the file structure above with the latest error

Comment: hi on further investigation I found out that Multer is causing issue getting the below error message : Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir